# Fetching the stores in a single page which starts with 0-9

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch all store names that start with numbers from 0-9 in a single page. If I write `$_GET['store'] == '1'` it gets only stores who has the first alphabet '1', but I want to fetch all stores from 0-9.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqxul.png

if i click on 0-9 then it should show all names from 0-1.

```
if(isset($_GET['stores']) && $_GET['stores'] != '') { 
                    $brands = $_GET['stores'];

                    $sub_stores_query = "SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE Name LIKE '$brands%'";
                    $sub_stores_result = mysqli_query($User->con, $sub_stores_query);
                    $sub_stores_count = mysqli_num_rows($sub_stores_result); 
            ?>
                <div id="<?PHP echo $cat; ?>" class="sub-cats-box">
                    <div class="row">
                    <?PHP if($sub_stores_count) {
                            while($sub_stores_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_stores_result)) { ?>
                        <div id="sub-cats-a" class="col-sm-6">

                            <a href="../store/?store=<?PHP echo $sub_stores_row['Name']; ?>">
                                <span><?PHP echo $sub_stores_row['Name']; ?></span>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    <?PHP } } else { ?>
                        <div id="sub-cats-a" class="col-sm-12">

                            <p class="text-danger"><strong>No stores in this category</strong></p>

                        </div>
                    <?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: please explains better your problem and write some code to let us help you

Comment: I ve added it  .

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a preg_match

```
if (preg_match('/^\d', $_GET['store']) 
{
  #  code for true ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `foreach` and `preg_match`. Sample usage:

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]', $k)
        echo 'key '.$k.' matches'."\n";
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]', $v)
        echo 'value '.$v.' matches'."\n";
}
```

Can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.